# Windows Command line get date

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have to execute a program.exe that generate me reports for a range of dates, I call the program.exe in a command line but i have to set two argument (**current date** and  **current_date-6days**) when I call it :

`c:\program.exe current_date current_date-6 (date before 6 days)`

i found that this command gives me the current date : 28-06-2013
`%date:~0,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%`

but I can't get the **current_date**-6  (means the date 6 days before)

i have also to let the user choose the range of date he want ...

how I can proceed to execute the program 1 )automatically (windows schedular) by giving him the two parametres  (current date , and date of 6 days before for example) 2) and manually in the same time, by giving the users the possibility of choosing a range of dates

```
@echo off

set /a currd=%date:~0,2%
set /a currm=%date:~3,2%
set /a curry=%date:~6,4%

set /a d=%date:~0,2%
set /a m=%date:~3,2%
set /a y=%date:~6,4%

FOR %%A IN (1 2 3 4 5 6) DO (
    :loop
      set /a d-=1

      if %d% LSS 1 (
        set d=1
        set /a m-=1

        if %m% LSS 1 (
          set m=12
          set /a y-=1
        )
      )
    xcopy /d:%m%-%d%-%y% /l . .. >nul 2>&1 || goto loop
)

start /WAIT /B "" "C:\MyPGM.exe" "%d%-%m%-%y%" "%currd%-%currm%-%curry%"
```

for the 28/06/2013 I have no problem but for the 01/07/2013 it generate me an error 
 "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: 1) this `%date:~0,2(-6)%` doesn't work for me. Do you mean `%date:~0,2%` ? 2) what do you mean with `currend_date-6` ?  3) please specify your date format (the output of `echo %date%`.

Comment: Why don't you have the program you coded just accept one date, and calculate the `current_date - 6 days` from it? It's much easier to do that than to do it in a batch file. (If it's always the current_date, the batch file doesn't even need to pass it; your exe can get it when it runs, so the batch file just has to start it.)

Comment: Yeah, what Ken said. If the exe always starts with the current date, maybe the only parameter passed in is your offset (6 in this case). Want to run it bi-weekly? Change the job scheduler to fire every 14 days instead of daily, and pass in 13 instead of 6.

Comment: currend_date-6 means the date before 6 day of he current date ,

Comment: #railsdog :this program generate me the reports of a range of dates (i must give it a strat date (curent date) and en_date (6 days before for example))
#Endoro : currend_date-6 (means the date 6 day before the current date)

Comment: So change your program to accept a starting date and a number of days to subtract from it. Your program is still a better place to do date math than a batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This VBS script has the ability to give you date - 6 and today.

Launch it to see the help.

```
:: Date foward & backward
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
echo to get todays date use         call "%~n0" today 0
echo to get yesterdays date use     call "%~n0" today -1
echo to get 25 days before 19441213 call "%~n0" 1944/12/13 -25
echo to get 1250 days in the future call "%~n0" today 1250
echo.
echo Add a third parameter if you want a separator in the date string
echo EG: to use - as in YYYY-MM-DD for today's date
echo     call "%~n0" today 0 -
echo.
pause
goto :EOF)

set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set day=%result:~0,4%%separator%%result:~4,2%%separator%%result:~6,2%
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer it works great, 
now i'm trying to put a fixed inputs (always today -1)
how can i change it in the code

Comment: Remove the help.  `set date1=today` and `set qty=-1` <--change those lines. change `set separator=-` if you want a minus sign as the separator, or leave it blank.

Comment: yes i already try it but it doesn't work :
erRor message is DESPLAYED VERY TIME i RUN THE BATCH FILE / 1 WAS unexpected at this time.

Comment: Yes, it does work.  remove every line up until `set date1=%1` and modify it.  Put the `@echo off` back too.  Make sure you don't add spaces before or after the parts you change.

Comment: sorry again ,  the code i put must ignore weekend (eg: if it's Monday it will get the last Friday date but whatever)

Answer (score 3):

This is a pure Batch solution that get the number of days to subtract in first parameter:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set Current_date=%%a-%%b-%%c
   set /A dd=1%%a-100, mm=1%%b-100, yyyy=%%c
)
set /A a=(mm-14)/12, jdn=(1461*(yyyy+4800+a))/4+(367*(mm-2-12*a))/12-(3*((yyyy+4900+a)/100))/4+dd-32075-%1
set /A l=jdn+68569,n=(4*l)/146097,l=l-(146097*n+3)/4,i=(4000*(l+1))/1461001,l=l-(1461*i)/4+31,j=(80*l)/2447
set /A dd=l-(2447*j)/80,l=j/11,mm=j+2-(12*l),yyyy=100*(n-49)+i+l
if %dd% lss 10 set dd=0%dd%
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
set Previous_date=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%
echo Current date:               %Current_date%
echo Current date minus %1 days: %Previous_date%
```

For example:

```
>test 6
Current date:               29-06-2013
Current date minus 6 days: 23-06-2013

>test 60
Current date:               29-06-2013
Current date minus 60 days: 30-04-2013

>test 600
Current date:               29-06-2013
Current date minus 600 days: 07-11-2011
```

Reference: http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm#comp

Comment: @user1863359: If this answer worked best for you, you should accept it as the correct answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/172661) or the [help] pages on accepting answers for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (date operations) very easily with some other language. Here are examples in Perl, Python, and Powershell.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET PERL_CMD=perl -MPOSIX -e "print(POSIX::strftime(q(%%d-%%m-%%Y),localtime(time()-6*86400)));"
FOR /F %%d IN ('%PERL_CMD%') DO SET PREV_DATE=%%d
ECHO %PREV_DATE%

SET PYTHON_CMD=py -3 -c "from datetime import *; print((datetime.now()+timedelta(days=-6)).strftime('%%d-%%m-%%Y'));" 
FOR /F %%d IN ('%PYTHON_CMD%') DO SET PREV_DATE=%%d
ECHO %PREV_DATE%

SET POWERSHELL_CMD=powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-Date ((Get-Date).AddDays(-6)) -format dd.MM.yyyy"
FOR /F %%d IN ('%POWERSHELL_CMD%') DO SET PREV_DATE=%%d
ECHO %PREV_DATE%
```

If you absolutely *must* do it in batch/CMD, then it could be (mostly) accomplished by parsing a date string and doing the math on the day, month, and year values.