# Turn XML data to HTML table with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to be able to turn a flat xml data sets into html tables, and I'm having trouble finding syntax examples that will fit my need. I would like to use one stylesheet that can convert similar looking data sets into html tables with variable columns.
this is  a part of my XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLT_StyleSheet.xsl"?> <Services>

  <Service WsdlUrl="http://venus.eas.asu.edu/WSRepository/Services/BasicThreeSvc/Service.svc">
    <Name>ServiceName</Name>
    <Provider></Provider>
    <Category>CatName</Category>
    <Operations>
      <Operaion>
        <Name>HelloWorld</Name>
        <MsgIn>elloWorldInputMessage</MsgIn>
        <MsgOut>HelloWorldOutputMessage</MsgOut>
      </Operaion>
      <Operaion>
        <Name>OP2name</Name>
        <MsgIn>InputMessage</MsgIn>
        <MsgOut>OutputMessage</MsgOut>
      </Operaion>
 <Operaion>
        <Name>Op3Name</Name>
        <MsgIn>InputMessage</MsgIn>
        <MsgOut>OutputMessage</MsgOut>
      </Operaion>     
    </Operations>
```

this how the HTML table must look Like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you did not find examples of transforming XML to HTML with XSLT, then you didn't look very hard.  That's one of its primary motivations.  Anyway, this should get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Services">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>XSLT example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Service">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Operations">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Type</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Operaion"> <!-- [sic] -->
        <xsl:variable name="service" select="ancestor::Service"/>

        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$service/Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$service/Category"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Output on your (corrected) document (it was missing end tags):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>XSLT example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Type</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>ServiceName</td>
                    <td>HelloWorld</td>
                    <td>CatName</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ServiceName</td>
                    <td>OP2name</td>
                    <td>CatName</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ServiceName</td>
                    <td>Op3Name</td>
                    <td>CatName</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for the first sight it seems to be ok but when i try to open the XML file in a browser it doesn't appear like a table here the two files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gggkh4wg94simrl/2GbiHAGkVF

Comment: As TimC noted in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19751667/4525), you should use CSS to style the table.  Please mark this answer as accepted, since you are using the code (and in fact claiming it as your own).  You are going to burn out stackoverflow as a resource if you always have to be asked to do basic things like [provide code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18361330/4525) and [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17378277/4525).

Comment: It's clear ,but take it easy it was with good faith, i'm still learning !
thank you for the answer